# MongoDB Geospatial and createdAt sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a headache for a idea how to properly sort data from a MongoDB. It is using `2dsphere` index and has timestamp `createdAt`. The goal is to show latest pictures (that what this collection is about, just a field mediaUrl...) but it has to be close to the user. I'm not very familiar with complex MongoDB aggregation queries so I thought here's a good place to ask. Sorting with `$near` shows only items sorted by distance. But there's a upload time, e.g. if item is 5 min fresh but is like 500 meters far than older item it still should be sorted higher.

Ugly way would be to iterate every few hundreds meters and collect data but maybe there's a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

So if I am correct you want to be able to sort on 2 fields ?

- distance
- timestamp

You should check out this method:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

It allows you to sort multiple columns.